# Calculating $\sum\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

I know it converges via comparison test, but how to actually find the series value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way you knew to manipulate the summand like this?

Comment: @Chio it's a really common method called partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand. Then I just compute each term's sum, yes?

Comment: Since I can break each term into another partial fraction decomposition!

Comment: And then those telescope. Thanks!

Comment: @Chio You needn't even split the terms given inasmuch as the right-hand side already is telescoping.  ;-)) -Mark